# Swiper, when click next button highlighter not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I am using swiper with a highlighter component. First 3 slides has highlighter but when I click next button 4th slide half highlighted and for the rest of the slides highlighter stop working. This is the gif of the situation.

https://imgur.com/MTfuHEZ

This is my swiper component code

```js
import Swiper, { Navigation } from "swiper";
import "swiper/swiper.min.css";

Swiper.use([Navigation]);

export default function FeaturesSwiper() {
  const [swiperInitialized, setSwiperInitialized] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const swiperRef = useRef<Swiper | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const carousel = new Swiper(".testimonials-carousel", {
      breakpoints: {
        320: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        640: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        1024: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
        },
      },
      grabCursor: true,
      loop: false,
      centeredSlides: false,
      initialSlide: 0,
      spaceBetween: 24,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".carousel-next",
        prevEl: ".carousel-prev",
      },
    });
    setSwiperInitialized(true);
  }, []);

  return (

          <div className="relative before:absolute before:inset-0 before:z-20 before:-translate-x-full before:bg-gradient-to-l before:from-transparent before:to-slate-900 before:to-20% after:absolute after:inset-0 after:z-20 after:translate-x-full after:bg-gradient-to-r after:from-transparent after:to-slate-900 after:to-20%">
            <div className="testimonials-carousel swiper-container group">
              <Highlighter
                className="swiper-wrapper w-fit"
                refresh={swiperInitialized}
              >
                {/* Carousel items */}
                {features.map((feature) => (
                  <HighlighterItem
                    key={feature.title}
                    className="swiper-slide group/slide h-auto"
                  >
                    <div className="relative z-20 h-[210px] overflow-hidden rounded-[inherit] bg-slate-900">
                      <div className="">
                        <div className="grow">
                          <div className="">
                            {feature.title}
                          </div>
                          <div className="">
                            {feature.description}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </HighlighterItem>
                ))}
              </Highlighter>
            </div>
          </div>

 <button className="carousel-next group relative z-20 flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center"
         onClick={() => {
           setSwiperInitialized(true);
           if (swiperRef.current) {
             swiperRef.current.slideNext();
           }
         }}
>
  <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
</button>
```

and this is the 'Highlighter' and 'HighlighterItem' components

```js
"use client";

import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MousePosition from "@/components/utils/mouse-position";

type HighlighterProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  refresh?: boolean;
};

export default function Highlighter({
  children,
  className = "",
  refresh = false,
}: HighlighterProps) {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const mousePosition = MousePosition();
  const mouse = useRef<{ x: number; y: number }>({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const containerSize = useRef<{ w: number; h: number }>({ w: 0, h: 0 });
  const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState<Array<HTMLElement>>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    containerRef.current &&
      setBoxes(
        Array.from(containerRef.current.children).map((el) => el as HTMLElement)
      );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    initContainer();
    window.addEventListener("resize", initContainer);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", initContainer);
    };
  }, [setBoxes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onMouseMove();
  }, [mousePosition]);

  useEffect(() => {
    initContainer();
  }, [refresh]);

  const initContainer = () => {
    if (containerRef.current) {
      containerSize.current.w = containerRef.current.offsetWidth;
      containerSize.current.h = containerRef.current.offsetHeight;
    }
  };

  const onMouseMove = () => {
    if (containerRef.current) {
      const rect = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      const { w, h } = containerSize.current;
      const x = mousePosition.x - rect.left;
      const y = mousePosition.y - rect.top;
      const inside = x < w && x > 0 && y < h && y > 0;
      if (inside) {
        mouse.current.x = x;
        mouse.current.y = y;
        boxes.forEach((box) => {
          const boxX =
            -(box.getBoundingClientRect().left - rect.left) + mouse.current.x;
          const boxY =
            -(box.getBoundingClientRect().top - rect.top) + mouse.current.y;
          box.style.setProperty("--mouse-x", `${boxX}px`);
          box.style.setProperty("--mouse-y", `${boxY}px`);
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={className} ref={containerRef}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

type HighlighterItemProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
};

export function HighlighterItem({
  children,
  className = "",
}: HighlighterItemProps) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`relative overflow-hidden rounded-3xl p-px before:pointer-events-none before:absolute before:-left-48 before:-top-48 before:z-30 before:h-96 before:w-96 before:translate-x-[var(--mouse-x)] before:translate-y-[var(--mouse-y)] before:rounded-full before:bg-mainBlue before:opacity-0 before:blur-[100px] before:transition-opacity before:duration-500 after:absolute after:inset-0 after:z-10 after:rounded-[inherit] after:opacity-0 after:transition-opacity after:duration-500 after:[background:_radial-gradient(250px_circle_at_var(--mouse-x)_var(--mouse-y),theme(colors.slate.400),transparent)] before:hover:opacity-20 after:group-hover:opacity-100 ${className}`}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I make highligter to work for every slide?

Note: I am a junior dev so I hope this is a proper way to ask my question and I tried to simplified the code as much as I can.